# Java constructing an http request message

Tags: java, http, sockets

I asked a similar question in another thread but I think I'm just having trouble getting the syntax right at this point. I basically want to open a socket in Java, send a HTTP request message to get the header fields of a specific web page. My program looks like this so far:

```
            String server = "www.w3.org"; 
            int port = 80; 
            String uri = "/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html#sec5.1"

            Socket socket = new Socket(server, port); 

            PrintStream output = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream()); 
            BufferedReader socketInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            output.println("HEAD " + uri + " HTTP/1.1");

            //String response = ""; 
            String line = ""; 
            while((line = socketInput.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println(line);  
            }

            socketInput.close();
            socket.close();
```

It doesn't really work. Or it doesn't work for all websites. If someone could just tell me the immediate problems with what I'm doing, that would be great. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
output.println("HEAD " + uri + " HTTP/1.1");
```

to

```
output.println("HEAD " + uri + " HTTP/1.1");
output.println("Host: " + server);
output.println();
```

You have to send the `Host` header because usually there are more than one virtual host on one IP address. If you use `HTTP/1.0` it works without the `Host` header.

Answer (score 1):

I would use some higher-level component, like `HttpURLConnection` ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests/2793153#2793153)) or [apache http components](http://hc.apache.org/).

Comment: That was suggested to me, but I'd like to see if this will actually work.